# CSS not working on spritesheet loaded in manifest

Tags: jquery, createjs

I am loading all my page elements using a manifest in createjs. However the css does not get applied to the spritesheet.

```
 //css
 .btn{background-position: -200px 0px; position: absolute; width: 100px;height:101px;opacity:1;margin-left: 1px;margin-top: 49px};

 //javascript
 manifest =[
      {src:"images/spritesheet.png", id:"spritesheet"}

 };

 loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
 loader.loadManifest(manifest);

 loader.on("complete", handleComplete, this);

 function handleComplete(){
       var btn = loader.getResult("spritesheet");
            $(".btn").append(_btn)
 }
```

It works when I load in the image from the css though so I must be doing something wrong. I have tried a couple of things but still having an issue.

```
 .selection_btn01{background-image: url(images/spritesheet.png); background-position: -200px 0px; position: absolute; width: 100px;height:101px;opacity:1;margin-left: 1px;margin-top: 49px};
```

I tried to add .css({"background-position": "-200px 0px"}) after the .append() thinking that maybe the image had to be loaded before the css was applied.

All I get is the entire spritesheet displaying all the states being displayed. Any tips would be greatly appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the above example the following is returned

```
 btn = <img src="images/spritesheet.png">
```

when actually this is what I needed to do to get the desired result

```
 $(".btn").css({"background-image": 'url('+_btn.src+')'});
```